# PHP get_file_contents not getting CSS content

Tags: php

I have got the following line of code which should echo out my CSS, however it is simply displaying nothing...

`echo file_get_contents('https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css')`

Any ideas? Makes no sense as to why this isn't working as the css file is there.

Comment: See the tip and warning in http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and the syntax.

Comment: or just include the file

Comment: Any particular reason why your css is on a remote server? Normally those go in local directories so all you have to do is then `echo file_get_contents('/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css');`

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents('https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css')` on its own produces no output. You might one of

```
$css=file_get_contents('https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css');
echo $css;
```

or just

```
echo file_get_contents('https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css');
```

Comment: I did do `echo file_get_contents('url')` just forgot mention that in my post, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Bit long but proper way to read content from file:

```
$file = 'https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css';
if (file_exists($file) and is_readable($file)) {
  echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```

You can use this code in case file located on the same machine where you run this script. But in your case, you're using external file (hosted on another machine) so you have to do something like this:

```
$url = 'https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    throw new RuntimeException(curl_error($ch));
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: The above IF statement appears to be false, so the file isn't readable, why would this be?

Comment: Maybe because it is restricted by the remote server?

Comment: @Jaspa It isn't redirected, you can check by `curl https://wholelifeclinics.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.min.css`.